# js-data-sql DSSqlAdapter create left join for hasOne Relationships

Tags: node.js, knex.js, jsdata

We are using `js-data-sql` [DSSqlAdapter](http://www.js-data.io/docs/dssqladapter) in our backend nodejs service.
Our model definition has a `hasOne` Relationship defined as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'covariance_predictions',
    idAttribute: 'id',
    relations: {
      belongsTo: {
        assets: {
          localKey: 'asset_1_id',
          localField: 'Covariance_Predictions'
        }
      },
      hasOne: {
        currencies: {
          localField: 'currency',
          localKey: 'currency_id'
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

We call the adapter using:

```
covariancePredictions.findAll(params, {
   with: ['currencies']
})
```

**Question**

After enabling `knex` debugging, we figured out, that it does not use a `left join` statement, but a subsequent SQL query like:

```
sql: 'select "currencies".* from "currencies" where "id" in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' }
```

Does anyone has any idea how to make `js-data-sql` [DSSqlAdapter](http://www.js-data.io/docs/dssqladapter) build a `left join` instead? Like:

```
select "covariance_predictions".id, [...], "currencies".code from "covariance_predictions" left join "currencies" on "currencies".id = "covariance_predictions".currency_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the maintainers of `js-data-sql`.  This is currently not supported as all relations loaded via `with` are done so using [loadingWithRelations](https://github.com/js-data/js-data-sql/blob/master/src/index.js#L80) which performs the subsequent `select ... where "id" in (...)` for each relation requested.

Loading `hasOne` and `belongsTo` as part of the original query should definitely be possible via a `left outer join`, but not an `inner join` as the loading of the original entity is not dependent on the existence of a relation(s).

I've created a [github issue](https://github.com/js-data/js-data-sql/issues/68) to track this change, although I'm not sure when I'll be able to make it as `js-data-sql` also needs to port over to extend [js-data-adapter](https://github.com/js-data/js-data-adapter) for `js-data` 3.0

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I updated the question to generate left joins and supported your github issue.